# Get transform property from SVG and modify - JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, transform

I have this html

```
<g id="testId1">
    <a id="testId2" xlink:href="###">
      <circle class="visited" id="p7" cx="100.94320759472402" cy="68.48130723347056" r="10"></circle>
      <use xlink:href="#checkmark" transform="translate(100.94320759472402 68.48130723347056)" class="check-icon"></use>
    </a>
  </g>
```

I need to modify with Javascript if it's possible, the "transform" attribute of 'use' with the same translate value but adding a scale(2)

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible to do?

Comment: Sure, where are you stuck?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't know how to mantain this "transform='translate'" value and add a scale(2) with Javascript

Comment: You can append other transformations to the attribute like so `transform="translate(100.1 68.5) scale(2)"`. So first need to get the current transform via `let currentTransform = el.getAttribute('transform')` and append them something like this `setAttribute('transform', 'currentTransform'+ scale(2)'`. Be careful not to confuse the css syntax with the native transformation properties of svg. See also [mdn docs: svg transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)

Comment: @herrstrietzel  Thank you! I have found the solution to the problem. I think I was making it too complicated